# Generate and format receipt style of text from Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text variable  `sendItems = ''` and a python dictionary:

```
items = {'Milk-Shake-49': ['Milk-Shake-49', '1234', '50', '2'], 'Dairy-Milk': ['Dairy-Milk', '12345', '800', 1]}
```

I want to populate sendItems with items before passing it to a print function as a receit style of text that I want to look as follows with reasonable spacing. Kindly help me out?

```
Item      Qty            Amount

Milkshake        2              50

DairyMilk        5              800
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to print it? Do you have actual code you need help with?

Comment: Why does the quantity of Dairymilk is 5? In the dict it seems to be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may e.g. use

```
items = {'Milk-Shake-49': ['Milk-Shake-49', '1234', '50', '2'], 'Dairy-Milk': ['Dairy-Milk', '12345', '800', 1]}

print('{:>15} {:>10} {:>10}'.format("Item", "Qty", "Amount"))

for key, values in items.items():
    print('{:>15} {:>10} {:>10}'.format(key, values[3], values[2]))
```

Which yields

```
           Item        Qty     Amount
  Milk-Shake-49          2         50
     Dairy-Milk          1        800
```

See [**PyFormat**](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) for more information.